# How to set CSS rule for a DIV in a LI?

Tags: html, css, class

I have a list of results from a query. That list will be displayed like that:

```
<div id='tabs'><ul>
  <div class = 'info'>
    <li>addr = "+detail[3]+"</li>
    <li>Interface = "+detail[0]+"</li>
    <li>time = "+detail[1]+"</li>
    <li>name = "+detail[2]+"</li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

my CSS :

```
.Redli
{ 
   list-style-position: outside;
   list-style-image:url("img/liimg3.gif"); 
}


.redmarkerinfo
{
   font-size:16px;
   font-weight:600;
   width:inherit;
   height:150;
   text-align:left;
   line-height: 24px;　　
   padding-top: 20px; 
   padding-bottom: 20px; 
   color:#333;
   background-color:#ffffff;
   font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

The problem is that my Redli rule can't work ???can someone explain why ??

Comment: Where is `class=Redli` in your HTML code?

Comment: your `.Redli` is ruled for nothing pal

Comment: I don't see a `div` in a `li` nor an object with the class `.Redli`. Please provide your question with clearer information.

Answer (score 2):

You must start your list with the ul tag and assign the class Redli to it

```
<ul class="Redli">
<li>..</li>
::
</ul>
```

Comment: Isn't it is too early to answer/vote? The question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

AS far as I know, you can't put a div inside a UL like that, try this:

```
<div id='tabs'>
  <div class='info'>
     <ul>
       <li class="Redli">addr = "+detail[3]+"</li>
       <li class="Redli">Interface = "+detail[0]+"</li>
       <li class="Redli">time = "+detail[1]+"</li>
       <li class="Redli">name = "+detail[2]+"</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not put `<ul>` befor `<div>`. Better to put it after and place a `class` on `<ul>`

Here's my code:

```
<div id='tabs'>
   <div class = 'info'>
    <ul class="Redli">
        <li>addr = "+detail[3]+"</li>
        <li>Interface = "+detail[0]+"</li>
        <li>time = "+detail[1]+"</li>
        <li>name = "+detail[2]+"</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the different with Barry's answer?

Comment: I think we have same answer but as I develop CSS and HTML, this is how I program a web application.